# User uploading files using blueimp's jquery file upload has very slow internet

Tags: javascript, jquery-file-upload

Is there anything else I can do to accommodate for slow internet on the user's side.

I'm using the file uploader in a .NET site, and there's already a 150MB restriction on files, anything above it would show an alert and not even attempt to process it.

I'm having users with 2-4Mb/s download speed (inaccurate as I'm using a small image download and JS to calculate their approximate internet speed) Trying to upload a large file, but presumably not larger than the limit.

Am I missing some sort of setting on the file uploader that would accommodate for large files at slow speeds or is it tough luck for all participating parties ?

The error I'm getting in .NET is:

> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out. at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent() at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetMultipartContent() at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() at System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureForm() at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm() at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull) at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at

Comment: Generally, consumer internet service has much faster download speed than upload speed.

Comment: @Pointy My point exactly, If their down is 2mb they'd be up all night trying to up a 100Mb file ...

Comment: @JamesThorpe I'm asking if there's some setting within the uploader that I have missed and/or not understood fully that would help towards resolving the issue. One'd expect users to know their limits but its astonishing how very few people are actually somewhat aware of their computer.

Comment: @ИвоНедев Now that you've included an actual error you're getting (having not mentioned it before!) it's a bit clearer :)

Comment: I've switched from [blueimp](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) to [fineuploader](https://fineuploader.com/) which is much faster in my scenario.